# First in first out subtract quantity stock?

Tags: c#

i have a database detail name item_detail

```
No(autoincrement)      Id_Item    qty
--------------------------------------
       1                  1        10
       2                  1        20
       3                  2        20
       4                  2        20
       5                  3        30
       6                  3        40
```

so for item 1 who came first in table is no 1 with sum all qty for item 1 is 30

if i have data from datagridview1 from my transaction

```
   Id_Item    qtyOUT
   ---------------
      1         20        
      2         30
```

how to subtract qty from datagridview1 to my database so the result i want like this

```
 No(autoincrement)     Id_Item    qty
--------------------------------------
       1                  1        0
       2                  1        10
       3                  2        0
       4                  2        10
       5                  3        30
       6                  3        40
```

so its checking if no 1 id item 1 only have qty 10 subtract till 0 then move id_item 1 who still has value , according to transaction number who came first.

after substract i wanna put that transaction process into table ITEM_TRANSACTION

```
 NoTrans(autoincrement) no(from item_detail)      qtyOut
---------------------------------------------------------
       1                       1                    10
       2                       2                    10
       3                       3                    20
       4                       4                    10
```

trycode

```
private void calculate()
{
// Transaction: Id_Item, qtyOUT
IEnumerable<ItemOut> contextItemOut = null;
// ItemDetail: No, Id_Item, qty
IEnumerable<ItemDetail> contextItemDetails = null;

Dictionary<int, decimal> itemOutQuantities = contextItemOut.ToDictionary(x => x.Id_Item, x => x.qtyOUT);

var itemDetails = contextItemDetails.OrderBy(x => x.No).ToList();

foreach (var item in itemDetails)
{
    decimal outQty;
    if (itemOutQuantities.TryGetValue(item.Id_Item, out outQty))
    {
        var qtyChange = Math.Min(outQty, item.qty);
        item.qty -= qtyChange;
        outQty -= qtyChange;
        if (outQty == 0)
        {
            ITEM_TRANSACTION trans = new ITEM_TRANSACTION();
            trans.id_Item = item;
            trans.qtyOut = qtyChange; //maybe its wrong
            itemOutQuantities.Remove(item.Id_Item);
        }
        else
        {
            itemOutQuantities[item.Id_Item] = outQty;
        }
    }
}

// itemDetails qty values are corrected
```

}

so please help

Comment: What is the logic? Both items for id 1 and 2 had changes in their values, but not 3..

Comment: its come from datagrid transaction because item 1 -20 and 2 -30 and the result i want in last table

Comment: i edit my post so u can understand

Comment: yeah if the value qty = 0 then move same id_item who still has value then subtract too

Comment: Using linq to remove items won't work.  You need a 2nd for loop to enumerate through the listitem array and subtract items from each row of the listitem until qtyout becomes zero.

Comment: how it works @jdweng ?

Comment: Exactly like you described in question.  foreach(var item in listitem){}.  Then subtract from item either the needed amount or all items.  You cannot subtract more items than in the database for each row,  Don't look for shortcuts because there aren't any.  It is just simple coding.

Comment: Is `Id_Item` unique in transactions or can there be multiple entries with same item ID?

Comment: @grek40 do you mean item_detail , yes it can be multiple

Comment: @InheavenA I mean datagridview1 or whatever the `qtyOUT` thing is... the multiple item_detail entries are clear from question.

Comment: @jdweng can u make example so i can understand , i still confused for moving item already 0 to item still has qty

Comment: @grek40 no its cannot

Comment: I did similar thing in SQL-Server, with while loop. I doubt, if there is any shortcut for this type of work. Its just a matter of coding the logic.

Comment: I don't understand how you get to the values in `ITEM_TRANSACTION` from the other example data (the 20 and 10 for `NoTrans` 3 and 4).

Comment: @grek40 for id_item 2 stock real or qty is 40 right (20+20) so after transaction -30 so qty become 10 right in the table (0,10) , the value transaction from (20-0) and (20-10) according No from item_details

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So `No`(item_detail) 5 and 6 are not shown because their `qtyOUT` would be 0.

Comment: yeah thats right , because in transaction id_item 3 not include so qtyout is 0

Comment: @grek40 please help my new post sir

Comment: @InheavenA I'll look into it... meanwhile, you can read about accepting answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, I assume your data are available as `IEnumerable<TEntity>` (don't keep them as `null` like my code does), you can adapt to a datatable or whatever value storage.

Turn your `qtyOUT` entries into a dictionary for efficient access, then loop your item_detail entries in `No` order and for each detail, check if there is a value to substract.

```
private void calculate()
{
    // Transaction: Id_Item, qtyOUT
    IEnumerable<ItemOut> contextItemOut = null;
    // ItemDetail: No, Id_Item, qty
    IEnumerable<ItemDetail> contextItemDetails = null;

    Dictionary<int, decimal> itemOutQuantities = contextItemOut.ToDictionary(x => x.Id_Item, x => x.qtyOUT);

    var itemDetails = contextItemDetails.OrderBy(x => x.No).ToList();

    // Data for ITEM_TRANSACTION
    ICollection<ItemTransaction> transactions = new List<ItemTransaction>();

    foreach (var item in itemDetails)
    {
        decimal outQty;
        if (itemOutQuantities.TryGetValue(item.Id_Item, out outQty))
        {
            var qtyChange = Math.Min(outQty, item.qty);
            item.qty -= qtyChange;
            outQty -= qtyChange;
            if (outQty == 0)
            {
                itemOutQuantities.Remove(item.Id_Item);
            }
            else
            {
                itemOutQuantities[item.Id_Item] = outQty;
            }

            if (qtyChange != 0)
            {
                transactions.Add(new ItemTransaction { /*No = autoincrement, */ NoTrans = item.No, qtyOUT = qtyChange });
            }
        }
    }

    // itemDetails qty values are corrected
}
```

Comment: if i want change to foreach for (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview1) how its works>? because my dt so complex

Comment: @InheavenA as far as I understand, `datagridview1` would be the one containing `qtyOUT`, so it needs to be converted to the dictionary. The loop iterates over the item detail entries.

Comment: i still dont get it itemOutQuantities[item.Id_Item] = outQty; can u explain it ?

Comment: @InheavenA The `itemOutQuantities` dictionary keeps track of the remaining `qtyOUT` value for each item ID. For example, `Id_Item=1` starts at `qtyOUT=20`. After item detail `No=1` is processed, the remaining `qtyOUT=10` because `10` where substracted from the first item detail. This remaining value is updated in the dictionary so that it can be used for the next item with same ID (item detail `No=2`)

Comment: if i wanna create new table from that transaction the column is 'id_item' and 'qtyout' for example for 'id_item1' , id_item_transaksi = 1 autoincrement , id_item=1 , qty_out=10 next row id_item_transaksi = 2 , id_item=1 and qty_out = 10 , i already create table using linq name ITEM_TRANSAKSI , so i know how much substract for each item how it works ?

Comment: and next row for is id_item_transaksi = 3 , id_item =2 , qtyout 20 , next row id_item_transaksi 4 , id_item = 2 , qtyout = 10

Comment: You commented that in the table with `qtyOUT` the `Id_Item` would be unique, so I don't understand your comment now. I think you need to clarify your table structure again in the question. Give each table a specific name and describe its properties so we can be sure to talk about the same things.

Comment: @InheavenA see my edit with `transactions` and `if (qtyChange != 0) ...` for building the `ITEM_TRANSACTION` table data.