# Reverse FIFO qty item?

Tags: c#

following my 1st post already solved
[First in first out subtract quantity stock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706332/first-in-first-out-subtract-quantity-stock)

i have a database detail name `Item_detail`

```
No(autoincrement)      Id_Item    qtyLimit     qtyReal      
-------------------------------------------------------
       1                  1          30           0
       2                  1          40           0
       3                  2          50           0
       4                  2          60          10
```

so for item 1  sum all qty Real for item 1 is 0 , and qty limit is limit qty for each data in detail item

if i have data from datagridview1 from `in_transaction`

```
   Id_Item    qtyIn
   ---------------
      1         50        
      2         80
```

how to add quantity from my transaction into my `update Item_detail` but **reverse** from bottom to upper
the result i want like this

```
 No(autoincrement)     Id_Item      qtyLimit     qtyReal
-------------------------------------------------------
       1                  1             30         10            
       2                  1             40         40           
       3                  2             50         30           
       4                  2             60         60
```

so its checking limit id no 1 if qty limit = qty real the move from bottom to upper with same no id then check again with qty limit

after that i wanna put that transaction process into table `Item_transaction`

```
 NoTrans(autoincrement) no(from item_detail)      qtyIn
---------------------------------------------------------
       1                       1                    10
       2                       2                    40
       3                       3                    30
       4                       4                    50
```

trycode

```
private void calculate()
{
// Transaction: Id_Item, qtyIn
IEnumerable<in_transaction> contextItemIn = null;
// ItemDetail: No, Id_Item, qtyLimit, qtyReal
IEnumerable<ItemDetail> contextItemDetails = null;

Dictionary<int, decimal> itemInQuantities = contextItemIn.ToDictionary(x => x.Id_Item, x => x.qtyIn);

var itemDetails = contextItemDetails.OrderBy(x => x.No).ToList();

foreach (var item in itemDetails.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
{
    decimal inQty;
    if (itemInQuantities.TryGetValue(item.Id_Item, out inQty))
    {
        var qtyChange = inQty
        item.qtyReal += qtyChange;
        inQty -= qtyChange;
        if (inQty == item.QtyLimit)
        {

            itemInQuantities.Remove(item.Id_Item);
        }
        else
        {
            itemInQuantities[item.Id_Item] = inQty;
        }
        if (qtyChange != 0)
        {
            transactions.Add(new ItemTransaction { /*No = autoincrement, */ 
            NoTrans = item.No, qtyIn = qtyChange });
        }
    }
}

// itemDetails qty values are corrected
```

}

so please help

Comment: Please correct your code... things like `qtyOUT`, `ItemOut` look like leftovers from your previous question. Also it would help if you explicitely give a name to each table, so we always know what we are talking about. Like first table `Item_Detail`, second table `In_Transaction`, 3rd table `Updated Item_Detail` fourth table `Item_Transaction`. You can chose different names of course, but anyway, name them somehow.

Comment: already edit my post @grek40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, only a few minor changes are needed to make this work.

So lets first establish the term of `Item_detail.capacity` as `qtyLimit - qtyReal`. The maximum change for a single item detail is limited by its `capacity`, while the desired change is given by `in_transaction.qtyIn`. So you can compute your quantity change for a single item as

```
var qtyChange = Math.Min(inQty, item.qtyLimit - item.qtyReal);
```

An entry from `in_transaction` is completed, when its remaining `inQty` is `0`, so change the condition

```
//if (inQty == item.QtyLimit) // <- wrong
if (inQty == 0)
    // ... remove
```

A minor side-change to simplify the code: instead of reversing the items later, start sorting them correctly.

```
var itemDetails = contextItemDetails.OrderByDescending(x => x.No).ToList();
foreach (var item in itemDetails)
```